# Importing csv issue in order to populate table on Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, import, csv, coupon

i got a problem while i was trying to populate a table on Magento 2.3[image]

I dont know why is this appearing, i was trying to populate the table salesrule_coupon with the following data on the csv

```
coupon_id,rule_id,code,usage_limit,usage_per_customer,times_used,created_at,type
10,1,R56Y2CU5FX8L,0,0,0,"2017-09-05 11:19:21",1
11,1,705E77MMDK3E,0,0,0,"2017-11-22 22:09:57",1
```

PLease help! i dont know what to do!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your code? I guess it might be because you might have not defined $masterAttributeCode.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/154026)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/154026)